# charging my Macbook Pro (85w) with my Macbook Air (45w) charger

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

seeing if anyone as done this. Has any used a 45w charger (like the one that comes with the Air) to charge their Macbook Pro? I left my Pro charger at a friends house and will not be able to get it before I leave town for a work trip, where I'll need the Pro. I'm  thinking that I can shut down the laptop and use the Air charger to charge it over night.

Has anyone done this? I'm worried about damaging the battery on the Pro.

Comment: The charger will report the max power it can output, and the MBP will not draw any more than 45W. Unfortunately, I can't find any references for that right now.

Answer (score 2):

It will be fine. The MacBook Pro will charge with the Air's charger well; it will just be slower than if it was on its original charger. One can even charge a MacBook Air with the charger for the MacBook Pro, if one wanted to.

I have attempted this myself and have had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Support: [Find the right power adapter and cord for your Mac notebook](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)

> Power adapters for Apple notebooks are available in 29W, 45W, 60W, and
>   85W varieties. You should use the appropriate wattage power adapter
>   for your Apple notebook. You can use a compatible higher wattage
>   adapter without issue, but it won't make your computer charge faster
>   or operate differently. **Lower wattage adapters will not provide
>   enough power.**

Note: I added bold text to the last sentence.

Comment: Experimentation shows that Apple notebooks will charge from power bricks with lower power ratings than the power brick that they came with.  Apple is covering itself from liability with their statement.  The claim of "not enough power" is a bit subjective.  45 watts  into a MacBook Pro is "enough power" to keep it operational but perhaps not add charge to the battery.  For some that is "enough".